# SAP HANA Express must be configured again once reboot

Tags: hana

I have download the SAP HANA Express 2.0 with application VM file and imported in Vmware successfully, and configured it. the database is running well but everytime once I reboot the OS and log in again , the system prompt I should re-config the HANA again, I should enter the Master password, determine whether I need proxy etc.. but the service is up because the connection is ok every I don't re-config it. any idea about this?

Thanks
Tony

Comment: Well, first off that ist not “normal”. The initial configuration is only necessary once. One thing that comes to mind is that you might have chosen volumes for the VM that don’t keep data changes after reboot. Can you confirm that you can actually store data in the file system that survives a reboot?

Comment: I think the data have saved in the file system because the password I changed first time is  available even I reboot and the data I stored in the database are exists, no any other exceptions except I need re-config after reboot. thanks.